# How to generate marker array in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2

I have 2 separate location data and I need to make array of them (*I guess I need to make array of them, maybe you have better idea!*) in order to add marker for both locations in google map.

**Code**

> Locations part are commented

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            requireContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            requireContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        ) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Allow location access", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    mFusedLocationClient = context?.let { LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(it) }!!

    mFusedLocationClient.lastLocation
        .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
            if (location != null) {
                // Location 1 (current location of user)
                val driverLatLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(driverLatLng, 15f))
                // Zoom in, animating the camera.
                mMap!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn())
            }
        }
    //new

    // Location 2
    val geoCoder = Geocoder(context)
    var address = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(customerAddressArgument, 1)!![0]

    val customerLatLng= LatLng(address.latitude, address.longitude)
    mMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(customerLatLng).title("Customer Location"))
    val cameraPosition = CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(customerLatLng) // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
        .zoom(17f)            // Sets the zoom
        .bearing(90f)         // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
        .tilt(30f)            // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
        .build()              // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition))
}
```

What I need is to make array of: `val driverLatLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)` and `val customerLatLng = LatLng(address.latitude, address.longitude)`

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for adding marker to map

first get both location point like location2 and location2

```
val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
// First marker
markerOptions.position(location1).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap

(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.ic_user_location)))
mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
 
 // second marker
 markerOptions.position(location2).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap

(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.ic_user_location)))
mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
// Move camera
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition))

// resize icon
private fun resizeIcon():Bitmap{
    val height = 120
    val width = 60
    val b: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_map_marker)
    val smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false)
    return smallMarker

}
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I set icon sizes?

Comment: @mafortis you have to resize your icon, I have edited my answer to add resize code

Comment: is it possible to take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66131984/get-google-map-accurate-location

Answer (score 0):

Create

```
var markerList:ArrayList<Marker> = ArrayList()
```

Create your marker

```
 val marker =  MarkerOptions().position(latlng).anchor(
            0.5f,
            0.5f
        ).title(your tittle).snippet(it.event_id).icon(your marker icon)
```

//Than add markers into marker list

markerList.add(marker)

use for loop to set the marker into google map

```
     markerList.forEach{
      // set marker to your google map with it
     }
```

Comment: Hi, appreciate your answer but I do not understand any of this half-half code you've shared (still newbie) would you mind complete your code? I've already share all variables that is required.

Comment: just add marker into markerArrayList and use for loop for access all marker and in for loop set the marker in google map