# Get google map accurate location

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2

I have following code which return user current location, but the location is not accurate

```
lateinit var mFusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

override fun onCreateView(...) {....}

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun getLastLocation() {
        mFusedLocationClient.lastLocation
            .addOnCompleteListener(requireActivity()) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful && task.result != null) {
                    mLastLocation = task.result
                    mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                    val driverLatLng = LatLng(mLastLocation.latitude, mLastLocation.longitude)
                    markerOptions.position(driverLatLng).title("Your location").icon(
                        BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(
                            driverIcon()
                        )
                    )
                    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
                } else {
                    Log.w("location", "getLastLocation:exception", task.exception)
                }
            }
    }
```

[image: one]

**Questions**

1. How to make current location more accurate
2. How to make blue circle more small, just to cover around current location pin (marker)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1)**

If you are not requesting the highest accuracy possible you need to set it to this value:

```
LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
```

This way the provider should use the device GPS if available instead of Wi-Fi/cell towers.
Official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html#connect). A code sample using high accuracy can be found [here](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/Fused-Location-API-Example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mindorks/example/fusedlocation/MainActivity.kt).

**Question 2)**

If I got your question right the circle represents the accuracy of the current location so with a higher precision the circle I suppose that the circle would become smaller. You just have to give it a try with the highest possible accuracy (just be sure that the device's GPS is being used and that it has a good signal)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, where should I place `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`? in code I shared in my question or in `onCreate()`, ...?

Comment: @mafortis I edited the answer adding  a link to a code sample. Let me know if that helped

Comment: thank you, but I wasn't able to make it work during last 58 minutes.

Comment: @mafortis do you mind upload the code somewhere so that I can give it a try? The fact that it is not working is too vague.

Comment: here you go https://gist.github.com/robertnicjoo/36cb35b230a239076c99f7709e82695c

Comment: PS: I've shared my original code exclude your answer so you can take look at it clean

Comment: @mafortis is it problem for you to share the whole project so that I can clone it and upload on AS quickly?

Comment: Yeaah, that would not be possible I'm afraid. you can just add this 2 files into empty project and then you have it

Comment: Ok, I'll try to do my best only by reading the code :) Take a look at this line in your gist: https://gist.github.com/robertnicjoo/36cb35b230a239076c99f7709e82695c#file-maptocustomerfragment-kt-L62. You are creating the request but you have to pass it to the client.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/Fused-Location-API-Example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mindorks/example/fusedlocation/MainActivity.kt#L30 . The snippet shows how to pass the customized request. Out of curiosity is your code receiving some locations?

Comment: Ok, I'm outside now but I'll check it in couple hours, and to answer you. Yes my code has 2 locations one from server (customer address) and other one which I'm trying to fix is driver location. So I'm trying to get driver location otw to customer location

Comment: @mafortis Ok, I uploaded a toy project on DB (https://www.dropbox.com/s/huc8vhrmpi3ploc/DELETEDELETEDELETE.zip?dl=0). The fused location provider is working (tested on a real device).

Comment: thank you for code but I have problem with undefined variables, I've fixed (changed) as much as I could but these are remained red `mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, mainLooper)` , `mainLooper` is red. Also note that I am not calling for location in `Activity` but in `Fragment` and that caused lots of changes in both `PermissionUtils` class and fragment.

Comment: Also ` ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            activity,` in `PermissionUtils` forced me to change to `fun requestAccessFineLocationPermission(activity: MapToCustomerFragment, requestId: Int) {` as it couldn't find `activity` in fragment ` PermissionUtils.requestAccessFineLocationPermission(` part

Comment: is it possible that you make `fragment sample` instead of activity?

Comment: Here is the fragment version: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cffxylzuzpufckz/TEMPFragment.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thank you, now I don't get any error but also I cannot see my driver location, used to be `val driverLatLng = LatLng(mLastLocation.latitude, mLastLocation.longitude)` and now I've added it under `override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {` in `locationResult.locations.forEach {` as  `val driverLatLng = LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude)`

Comment: Forget about that, it's showing but there is big issue :D, it keeps adding drivers pin (marker) to the map :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228530/discussion-between-paolo-and-mafortis).